# numpy.pad adds twice the padding than declared

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to pad a 2d numpy array to make it the size of the image I'm working on but the `np.pad` function pads twice the padding that I request:

```
import numpy as np

gaussian = [
    [0.003, 0.013, 0.022, 0.013, 0.003],
    [0.013, 0.059, 0.097, 0.059, 0.013],
    [0.022, 0.097, 0.159, 0.097, 0.022],
    [0.013, 0.059, 0.097, 0.059, 0.013],
    [0.003, 0.013, 0.022, 0.013, 0.003]
]

gaussian = np.pad(gaussian, ((2, 2), (2, 2)), 'constant')
```

The above code should ideally output a `(7, 7)` array (at least that's what I'm expecting), but instead I get the output as a `(9, 9)` 2d array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is behaving exactly as the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) states it will. In particular, the second parameter reads:

> **pad_width : *{sequence, array_like, int}***
>
> Number of values padded to the edges of each axis. ((before_1, after_1), … (before_N, after_N)) unique pad widths for each axis. ((before, after),) yields same before and after pad for each axis. (pad,) or int is a shortcut for before = after = pad width for all axes.

So you are asking for two additional elements on each side of your array in each dimension with `((2, 2), (2, 2))`. 2 + 5 + 2 = 9, as expected.

Examples of valid options for `pad_width` that would result in a 7x7 output array are

- `1`
- `(1,)`
- `((0, 2),)`
- `((2, 0), (1, 1))`

You probably want either of the first two if you intend for the padding to be symmetrical.

Comment: BRB, gonna drown myself

Comment: @sspatole. Been there done that. Leave the question open. You're probably not alone in this :)